# How to split string and get only one word in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string similar like this:

```
HELLO TEST PACKAGE PARIS1 PROJECT
```

I got this string from selecting row and column:

```
project_name = df[col_pro].values[row_pro]
```

and I want to get the "PARIS" only to be in a new column which is 'location_id'

I tried to split them, but it was hard for me to get the "PARIS" only.

How can I do this with python?
Thank you

Comment: do you need to get the PARIS from PARIS1?

Comment: Yes, I need to extract the PARIS from PARIS1

Comment: Is this the only one case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Named groups.
Say you have `df`;

```
                               text
0  HELLO TEST PACKAGE PARIS1 PROJECT
```

Using Named Groups

```
df.text.str.extract(r'(?P<location_id>PARIS)')
```

Comment: what if I need to be with all my existing columns?

Comment: `df.join(df.text.str.extract(r'(?P<location_id>PARIS)'))` Just use join

Answer (score 1):

First Split the string and replace the numbers by empty string

```
import re
project_name = 'HELLO TEST PACKAGE PARIS1 PROJECT'
project_name_list = fullname.split()

for i in range(len(project_name_list)):
  project_name_list[i] =(re.sub('\d', '', project_name_list[i]))
  
  
print(project_name_list)#['HELLO', 'TEST', 'PACKAGE', 'PARIS', 'PROJECT']
```

if you need to back to the string use str.join

```
project_name = ' '.join(project_name_list)#HELLO TEST PACKAGE PARIS PROJECT
```

Comment: thank you. Actually what I need is extracting the "PARIS" from the full project_name

Comment: I have updated my solution

Comment: Will replace all the integers in your project name by empty string